# Can I iterate through two loops of equal size with foreach?

Tags: php, for-loop, foreach

I'm new to PHP. I have two arrays `$array1` and `$array2` of equal size. I've been using `foreach` loops to iterate through arrays like so:

```
foreach($array1 as $element1) {
      //Do stuff with $element1
}
```

and

```
foreach($array2 as $element2) {
      //Do stuff with $element2
}
```

but now I'd like to iterate through both arrays at the same time so that I have access to both `$element1` and `$element2` in the loop body.

How do I do that?

Comment: Are the *keys* in the first array identical to those in the second?  This detail will dictate the answer.

Comment: excellent, that makes this easy.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
while (($element1 = next($array1)) !== false) {
  $element2 = next($array2);
  // Do something
}
```

But it will fail, if `false` is an allowed value in `$array1`. If (in this case) `false` is not allowed in `$array2`, you can just swap both

A "foreach"-solution (if both shares the same key)

```
foreach ($array1 as $i => $element1) {
  $element2 = $array2[$i];
  // Do something
}
```

A third (I think quite nice) solution, that just allows primitive types in `$array1`

```
foreach (array_combine(array_values($array1), array_values($array2)) as $element1 => $element2) {
  // Do something
}
```

Comment: The `next` trick will work as long as there are no `false`s in the first array.

Comment: Yes, I know, but I didnt found a (not so complex) solution for that. However, I added two other ways and at least one should fit :) The third one feels quite nice to me, but it has its limitations, too.

Answer (score 2):

[Each](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.each.php) returns an array containing the key and value, and advances the pointer to the next element.  It returns false once it has advanced past the last element.

```
// Iterate until one of the arrays is complete
while (($a = each($array_a)) !== false && ($b = each($array_b)) !== false) {
    echo "The key:value from array_a is {$a['key']}:{$a['value']}.\n";
    echo "The key:value from array_b is {$b['key']}:{$b['value']}.\n";
}
```

To iterate completely over both arrays, use || instead of &&.

Answer (score 1):

use a for loop instead...

```
for($i = 0;$i<count($array1);$i++) { 
    /* access $array1[$i] and $array2[$i] here */ 
}
```

This will work if the indexes of the arrays are numeric and the same for both arrays

Comment: Only works for numerical arrays.

Comment: this is not **foreach** loop... question `Can I iterate through two loops of equal size with foreach?`But yeah, it works for nums as keys :)

Comment: @Wh1T3h4Ck5, there are more ways to iterate over an array in PHP than there are to skin a cat.  All of them *can* be appropriate in a given circumstance.

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
$i = 0;
foreach($array1 as $element) {

    // Do stuff with the element
    $stuff_from_this_array = $element;
    $stuff_from_other_array = $array2[$i];
    $i++;

}
```

You'd obviously want to put $stuff_this_array and $stuff_from_other_array into something more persistent, but maybe this gives you an idea.

Comment: This breaks when the array does not have numeric, sequential keys.

Answer (score 0):

That is a possible solution. If you start with next() directly, you never get the first element of the array.

```
reset($array1); reset($array2);
for ($element1 = current($array1), $element2 = current($array2); 
        $element1 !== false && $element2 !== false; 
        $element1 = next($array1), $element2 = next($array2)) {
    // Do something

}
```