# PHP: Best way to iterate two parallel arrays?

Tags: php, loops, iteration

As seen [in this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5641619/can-i-iterate-through-two-loops-of-equal-size-with-foreach), there are several ways to iterate two same-sized arrays simultaneously; however, all of the methods have a rather significant pitfall.  Here are some of the caveats with the methods suggested:

- You can't use `FALSE` values in one of the arrays.
- You can only use scalar values in one of the arrays.
- You must use numerically indexed arrays.
- Both arrays must share the same keys.
- Etc.

My question is - *is there a method for doing this which doesn't suffer from any of these (or other) significant caveats?*

Bear in mind that I'm simply asking this out of curiosity; I have no use-case in mind, nor do I even know if such a case actually exists or would be useful/practical in a real-world scenario.  However, here is some example data:

```
$arr1 = [ 'a' => 1, 'b' => FALSE, 'c' => new DateTime() ];
$arr2 = [ 'foo', TRUE, 7 ];
```

Comment: What's wrong with beefsack's answer to that question? Seems like it would work regardless of the content or structure of the arrays.

Comment: it would not work with because  `'b' => FALSE` @nickb

Comment: @Baba - No, [it works with `'b' => false`](http://codepad.viper-7.com/nNZuNj).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use a [`MultipleIterator`](http://php.net/MultipleIterator):

```
$iterator = new MultipleIterator;
$iterator->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($array1));
$iterator->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($array2));

foreach ($iterator as $values) {
    var_dump($values[0], $values[1]);
}
```

You can find more examples concerning the various options [in the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/multipleiterator.construct.php#refsect1-multipleiterator.construct-examples).

Answer (score 4):

As of PHP 5.5 you can do this:

```
foreach (array_map(null, $array1, $array2) as list($item1, $item2))
{
    var_dump($item1);
    var_dump($item2);
}
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php#control-structures.foreach.list

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$arr1 = array( 'a' => 1, 'b' => FALSE, 'c' => new DateTime() );
$arr2 = array( 'foo', TRUE, 7, 5 );


reset($arr1);
reset($arr2);    

while ( (list($key, $val) = each($arr1))
    && (list($key2, $val2) = each($arr2))
) {
    var_dump($val,$val2);
    // or whatever you wanted to do with them
}
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.each.php

Comment: your script has error and would not work if total arrays in `$arr2` > `$arr1` ... correct it before they start voting you down

Comment: @Baba I had find a server to test, because I didn't really test it the first go. It wasn't a problem with the length of the arrays (from what I could tell), but there were problems (like I don't have 5.4 on the server I tested on), so thanks for pointing that out.