# How to Looping 2, or much array using foreach?

Tags: php, arrays, loops, for-loop, foreach

How to looping multi array using `foreach()`? Or how to define `$looping` on `for()`? I'm tired of using `AND` logic on `foreach()`.

This is my code:

```
<?php
$b=["a","b","c","d","5"];
$a=["1","3","4","5"];
foreach($a as $a && $b as $b) {
    echo $a.$b;
}

// AND logic Error

$tipe=trim(fgets(STDIN));
$post=trim(fgets(STDIN));
if($tipe == "1") {
    $url="http://example.com/api"
    $postdata="post_data={$post[$x]}";
}

for($x=0;$x<10;$x++) {
    $ch=curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$postdata);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_exec($ch);
}
// $x not defined
```

Comment: Could you provide a sample of code? What have you ever tried? Also, I don't understand the second part of the question, with `$looping`.

Comment: I bet the manual will be helpful for you. http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php and http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: `foreach($a as $a` $a is your array and you assign $a as your value. Meaning the value will overwrite the array.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: Best way to iterate two parallel arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10132210/php-best-way-to-iterate-two-parallel-arrays)

Comment: `// $x not defined` Well `$x` is not used either

Comment: `Im tired using AND logic on foreach` and it does not work either `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '&&' (T_BOOLEAN_AND), expecting :: (T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM) in`

Comment: On my code, if i using for() $x not defined, and if im using foreach, i can't looping 2 array

Comment: @user3677931..seems to me you're getting bigtime help... go read those tutorials and grow a spine, get your feet wet and hit your hit twice or more... then you get the experience of coding! http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/

Answer (score 0):

`$x` is not defined because the execution is stoped at your first foreach loop. You can't use foreach like you did but you can change it to:

```
$b = ["a","b","c","d","5"];
$a = ["1","3","4","5"];

foreach($a as $key => $value) {
    echo $value . $b[$key]; // just make sure to have at least the same number of elements in the $b array as the $a array has
}
```

However, it is hard to understand what exactly you want to achieve with this code and what it is supposed to do.

Comment: notice: Array to string conversion in /storage/sdcard1/telegram.php on line 70                                                                 PHP Notice:  Array to string conversion.    $postdata="chat_id={$cid}&photo={$jpg}&caption={$status}";      i want looping $jpg=array and $status=array on $postdata

Answer (score 0):

You have to first take the max count of array values & then iterate the loop till max count, I hope this will help you

```
$b=["a","b","c","d","5"];
$a=["1","3","4","5"];

$max = ( count($a) > count($b) ) ? count($a) : count($b);

for( $i=0 ; $i<$max; $i++){
  $strA = (isset($a[$i])) ? $a[$i] : '';
  $strB = (isset($b[$i])) ? $b[$i] : '';

  echo $strA . $strB;
}
```